# Unable to use custom index in filebeat configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, elk

I'm working on elasticsearch version 7.2.0 and shipping the logs using filebeat. I can use the custom pipeline but I'm unable to set custom index name. Kindly help.

Below is my filebeat output configuration:

```
output.elasticsearch:
          # Array of hosts to connect to.
          hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
          pipeline: reindex_timestamp
          index: "logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template.name: "logstash"
setup.template.pattern: "logstash-*"
setup.template.enabled: true
setup.template.overwrite: true
```

Here I'm not sure though how I have to create a custom template that I specified the name

**Update: I found the solution to my requirement-** Below configurations worked for me since my requirement is to write weblogs( if logs contain **name: web**) in separate index and rest of the application logs in another index (now writing to default index called filebeat-*)

```
output.elasticsearch:
     # Array of hosts to connect to.
     hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
     #index: "filebeat-7.2.0-logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}" #Its not taking custom index
     pipeline: reindex_timestamp_logstash
     indices:
         - index: "node-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
         when.contains:
            name: web

     pipelines:
         - pipeline: reindex_timestamp_node
         when.contains:
           name: web
setup.template.name: "filebeat-7.2.0"
setup.template.pattern: "filebeat-7.2.0-*"
```

Comment: Just to be sure: The data ends up in an index `filebeat-*` rather than `logstash-*`? And even though there is no Logstash involved here you want to name the index like that (maybe for historical reasons)?